# Create a hash when a class object is initialized

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to create a hash when I initialize a class object.

```
def initialize
  @url = Hash.new
  Rails.application.routes.routes.named_routes.values.map do |route|
    @url[:request_method] = route.constraints[:request_method].to_s
    @url[:path] = route.path.spec.to_s
    @url[:controller] = route.defaults[:controller]
    @url[:action] = route.defaults[:action]
  end 
end
```

Once initialized, I am left with just the last returned value instead of a library of stuff to play with. How can I have a library of objects on creation instead of the last returned value?

Comment: There maybe an another simple way if you tell us what you are exactly trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to create a Hash that's internal to the class, or are you trying to create a class that's derived from Hash so it can pre-populate it? It seems odd you're using a hash as an internal store, it's conventional to use variables like `@request_method` instead. Additionally, `Hash.new` is used rarely. `@url = { }` is the conventional way to do it. You'd use the other for setting a default value or a handler block.

Comment: It's also worth noting you're using `map` to convert the routes into something, but you're not using it correctly. You're recycling the same structure for each route. You're returning `@url[:action]` for each iteration. You're discarding this result since `initialize` is one of the few methods for which the return value is ignored.

Comment: Thanks @tadman, could you demonstrate a way using variables that contain the list of items?

Comment: I'm just curious what your objective is here. Do you want a structure that holds a remapped interpretation of the routes?

Comment: @tadman yes exactly, for testing purposes. Is there something flawed in doing it this way?

Comment: Nothing wrong. Was just confirming.

Comment: By "class object", do you mean an object of the `Class` class? If that is the case, you should write so. Otherwise (and if you mean an object of some class), then you should write simply "object" as any object is an instance of some class, and your way of writing would be misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to collect and remap those, this should do it:

```
def initialize
  @urls = Rails.application.routes.routes.named_routes.values.map do |route|
    {
      request_method: route.constraints[:request_method].to_s,
      path: route.path.spec.to_s,
      controller: route.defaults[:controller],
      action: route.defaults[:action]
    }
  end 
end
```

You'd then create accessor methods to expose `@urls` in whatever format you want.

Comment: you are correct. Typing without thinking is a dangerous game :) +1